# Template Class Assignment Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, abstract-data-type

I'm having a little trouble with the following:

I'm writing a map abstract data type for some coursework & I've come across a problem whilst trying to assign an object of my class (MapEntry - below) to an array of the same type in the class MapADT. It tells me that:

Error  1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'MapEntry *' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\cross_000\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\objectorientedmethodsasignment1\mapadt\mapadt.h    14

So I thought I would write my own Assignment operator override. I've done this in the MapEntry class definition but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize it when I try to initialize the array in the constructor on MapADT - below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#pragma once

template <class Tk, class Tc>
class MapEntry
{
private:
    Tk key;
    Tc contents;
    bool isPopulated;

public:
    MapEntry() {

    }

    MapEntry(Tk keyInput, Tc contentsInput) {
        key = keyInput;
        contents = contentsInput;
        isPopulated = true;
    }

    MapEntry(Tk keyInput, Tc contentsInput, bool isPopulatedInput) {
        key = keyInput;
        contents = contentsInput;
        isPopulated = isPopulatedInput;
    }

    ~MapEntry() {
        //TODO
    }

    Tk getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    void setKey(Tk keyInput) {
        key = keyInput;
    }

    Tc getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    void setContents(Tc contentsInput) {
        contents = contentsInput;
    }

    bool getIsPopulated() {
        return isPopulated;
    }

    void setIsPopulated(bool isPopulatedInput) {
        isPopulated = isPopulatedInput;
    }

    MapEntry<Tk, Tc>& operator=(const MapEntry<Tk, Tc> & lst)
    {
        clear();
        copy(lst);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

MapADT.h

```
#pragma once
#include "MapEntry.h"

template <class Tk, class Tc>
class MapADT
{
private:
    int mapSize = 1000;
    MapEntry<Tk, Tc> *map;
public:
    MapADT() {
        map = new MapEntry<Tk, Tc>[mapSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) {
            map[i] = new MapEntry<Tk, Tc>(NULL, NULL, false);
        }
    }
}
```

There's more to the MapADT class but I don't think it's relevant. If you need to see the whole thing I can add it.

Comment: `map[i]` is of type `Tc`, and yet you try to assign it a `MapEntry<Tk, Tc>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map[i]` is not an pointer to `MapEntry`.

Not sure if you want

```
map[i] = MapEntry<Tk, Tc>(NULL, NULL, false);
```

or

```
MapEntry<Tk, Tc>** map;

MapADT() {
    map = new MapEntry<Tk, Tc>*[mapSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) {
        map[i] = new MapEntry<Tk, Tc>(NULL, NULL, false);
    }
}
```

to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks very much Jarod. I tried this earlier and the IDE wasn't giving me the feedback in the watch list that I had an array filled with items (I guess it doesn't support showing that information from an array of pointers) but if I output from an object pointed to by the array programmatically it seemed to work!

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
map = new MapEntry<Tk, Tc>[mapSize];
```

you allocate an array of `MapEntry<Tk, Tc>`, and default constructors are called for all of them. There's no need in subsequent `for` loop at all, you should just write proper initialization in `MapEntry::MapEntry()`, which is currently empty.

Comment: Thanks Anton, I also tried your version and it also worked. So thank you for taking the time to reply.